# accessing the parent accordion in nested accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

```
<li>
  <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" id="plus">ABC</a>
  <ul class="inner">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="toggle" id="plus">DEF</a>
      <div class="inner" id="mixedFaVT">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>

      <a href="#" class="toggle" id="plus">GHI</a>
      <div class="inner" id="mixedFaVA">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How do I access `ABC`, when `$this = DEF` or `$this = GHI`? The problem is, there are five other sets of nested accordions, in the same HTML page. To generalize the question, when `$this` is any 'inner' button like DEF/GHI, how do I access their particular parent ABC using jQuery? I have tried `.find()` and `.parents()`, but those do not work.

Comment: On a side note, IDs should be unique in an HTML page.

Comment: Depends what `$this` is. You haven't shown us that. Please take a few minutes to read [mcve]

Comment: this varies, but I am asking in the case where $this is either DEF/GHI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may traverse the parents of `$this` until the `ul` using the `parents()` method, and then get the previous element of it, which will be the `a`.

```js
var $this = $('#plus-1');
var parent = $this.parents('ul').prev();

console.log('$this:', $this.text());
console.log('parent:', parent.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" id="plus-0">ABC</a>
  <ul class="inner">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="toggle" id="plus-1">DEF</a>
      <div class="inner" id="mixedFaVT">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>

      <a href="#" class="toggle" id="plus-2">GHI</a>
      <div class="inner" id="mixedFaVA">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```